# How to import a JSTL taglib globally?

Tags: jsp, jstl

Is it possible to import a taglib like JSTL globally so that you don't need to define it for every single JSP page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do follow this way:

1. Separate your jsp page to three parts (header.jsp, body.jsp and footer.jsp).
2. Define a template to include those pages.
3. declare the taglibs in the header.jsp file.

Now you can use taglib in the body page.

Comment: suppose for example you have define your taglib inside your header.jsp, I tried it, you cant call JSTL function in your body.jsp
that simpy doesn't work !

Comment: you cant call suggested methods of tags when you're coding, but it's work fine when you deploy them to apache or tomcat server.

I tried with this appoach using struts framework and it working fine

Comment: suppose we have 4 pages: header - body - footer and main - now If I put JSTL definition in my header and import all pages in my main page, the JSTL call for example in body page doesn't work

Comment: I found the problem ! for unity in the page I should have change the scope of the <c:set to request !